# require() in nodeJS doesn't work with a module i just installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, npm-install

I'm trying to work with node.js for the first time. But I keep running into the same problem over and over.

I want to install a module from github. If I try installing it from the internet itself I keep getting warnings and errors. Save the zip file and extract it to my desktop and install from there. 
I think that works as seen in the image below.

[Install module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNXXs.png)

But later if I try running a script using the module I just installed. I get the error can't find module.

[Error running script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb9uc.png)

Can't figure out what is wrong. If I check the folder nodes.js/node_modules/got there is a folder with a index.js, package.json and licence file.

Comment: Do you run `npm install got -g`?

Comment: use `--save` for save that module in package.json ex `npm i --save module _name`

Comment: after adding all the modules did you run `npm install`

Comment: I did run npm install gotpath -g. Do you mean after I need to run npm install got -g again? In what path do I need to do this, the one of the script or the one of node.js. What does --save do?

Answer (score 0):

Now I know it makes sence but you need to install the module in the path of the script you are making and not in the installation path of nodejs.

Crazy how long I search for this simple answer